# Issues running powershell command to check status of remote servers services

Tags: powershell, service, windows-scripting

Title is pretty self explanatory, I'm having issues when running the below script against a list of servers and services. I keep ending up with the following error when I run it even though when I run a get-service on ex01 by itself, I can see the service and it's status. Not sure where the disconnect is, but any help is appreciated.

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'MsExchangeIS'.
```

At \dc01\c$\DriveMan\ServiceStatusCHK\Srvstatuscheck.ps1:12 char:31
+            $service_status = (Get-Service -Name $service).Status
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MsExchangeIS:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'continue'
$services = ("dns","dhcp","MsExchangeIS")
$servers  = 'dc01','dc02','ex01','ex02'


foreach($server in $servers){

$service_status = (Get-Service -Name $service).Status

    foreach($service in $services){

       #start-sleep -s 1



       if((((Get-Service -Name $service).status) -eq 'running')){

           "$service on $server is Running" | write-host -foregroundcolor green 

                } else  

                {"$service on $server is DOWN" | write-host -foregroundcolor red 

                } }}         

            pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the local computer for the services, not the remote computers.

```
Get-Service -Name $service
```

Should be

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service -computername $server -filter "name='$Service'"
```

However, you can do this without the loops because `Get-WMIObject` can take a collection of remote computers and a filter to specify multiple services.

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'continue'
$services = ("dns","dhcp","MsExchangeIS")
$servers  = 'dc01','dc02','ex01','ex02'
$filter = "";
foreach ($svc in $services) {
    $filter += "name = '$svc' or ";
}
$filter = $filter.Substring(0,$filter.Length-4);
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -filter $filter -ComputerName $servers|select-object -property pscomputername,name,state | format-table -autofit;
```

Comment: How would I color the output based on whether a service I defined was running or not?

Comment: You can't with `format-table`. You'd have to iterate over each item returned by `get-wmiservice`, test, and use `write-output`